# Подскажите, как лучше организовать хранение данных view (ширина,высота,отступы)

Tags: java, android, mvc

В приложении есть несколько (а точнее довольно много) этапов. Каждый этап  (отдельное активити) имеет набор `imageViews` (на каждом этапе - разное количество). Размеры (ширина, высота), а также отступы от границ контейнера каждый `imageView` получает из массива, созданного в каждом активити:

```
int[] viewsWidth={100,150,200,...}
int[] viewsHeight={120,100,180, ...}
int[] viewsLeftMargin ={20,150,30,80, ...}
int[] viewsTopMargin ={180,250,50,120, ...}
ImageView[] imageViews ={image1,image2,imge3,image4, ...}
```

далее эти данные в методе `createImageViews()` , который находится в `oncreate`, обрабатываются так, чтобы картинки на разных дисплеях выглядели корректно (*т.е. для большего дисплея размеры картинки и отступы увеличиваются, для меньшего - уменьшаются*).

Ну, и так происходит на каждом этапе (активити): создается 4 массива + массив ImageViews,+ метод, который все это обрабатывает.

Напрашивается мысль все это упростить, но вот как? По принципу MVC? Я не слишком большой специалист в java, у меня маловато опыта.

К примеру, можно поместить все массивы (за исключением массива с картинками, разумеется) в файл ресурсов, причем массивы будут содержать параметры всех ImageView в приложении,а не только одного активити. Затем создать модель (Model1), которая свяжет 4 параметра{ширина, высота, отступслева, отступсверху}, затем создать класс, который создаст List (paramsViewList)из объектов Model1, и потом в каждом активити созданному массиву imageView в методе `createImageViews()`присваивать соответствующие значения из paramsViewList.

Я вообще правильно мыслю, и не будет ли этот вариант усложнением (*на самом деле*), а не улучшением кода, и есть ли какие-то более интересные идеи?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать стандартные механизмы системы [dimensions ресурсы](https://metanit.com/java/android/2.6.php)?

Comment: @eugeneek насчет того, чтобы поместить все массивы в файл ресурсов, я написала. Это будет в любом случае правильным, т.к. правильно хранить такого рода данные в ресурсах.

Comment: Так вы про эти ресурсы говорили. Да, всё верно, для этого их и придумали. И никакие модели, листы не нужны. Просто указывайте эти параметры в layout и всё.

Comment: @eugeneek тогда будет много почти дублирующего кода во всех активити. В первом активити я буду создавать 4 массива с параметрами (но уже используя ресурсы) + массив ImageView, во втором опять 4 массива, в третьем опять 4 массива+ массив ImageView. если не создавать массивы, а ссылаться на строки из ресурсов, то еще код добавиться... Вот о чем я пишу. Где-то (по логике) должно быть одно место, один класс, который хранит данные для всех ImageView всех активити, а в каждом конкретном активити они получаются из этого класса, но нужно будет создавать в каждом активити свой массив imageView.